# Can ffplay view subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

I've searched through the internet to view subtitles during playing a movie with ffplay but no luck, or maybe I'm too dumb.  The extension file is .mts

thanx

Comment: `ffplay` is a simple player: it's more of a testing tool or example than a typical player. Show the full output of `ffmpeg -i input`. I don't have an equivalent sample to test at the moment, but when playing you could try pressing `t` during playback to cycle the subtitles.

Comment: I just use a bat file in VB6 to play any movie.  Some have Subtitles, like the .mts extension, and VLC can play them with the subtitles    FFPLAY.EXE     "MovieName.mts"   >

Answer (score 12):

You have to use

```
ffplay -vf subtitles=filename=input.mkv input.mkv
```

Equivalent to `-vf "subtitles=input.mkv"`

Please find more information [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1).

Comment: This didn't work for `dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)` from a .ts fle:
`[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7ffca4c7c440] Only text based subtitles are currently supported`

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a fine time with `ffplay -vf subtitles=<subtitles file> <video file>`
`-vf` is "video filter"